# Slow page loading compared to non-automated browser

Tags: puppeteer

I'm noticing that page loads with Puppeteer is incredibly slower than using a normal browser without automation. An example would be loading the YouTube homepage. When I open chrome in incognito and go to the YouTube homepage, it loads within a few seconds. Doing the same thing with puppeteer and it's taking at least 2x as long to load the homepage.

I've tried using the stealth plugin, the adblock plugin, I'm currently blocking resources that aren't needed (images, css, etc), tried adding these options to the args:

'--proxy-server="direct://"',"--proxy-bypass-list=*"

And through all of that, the changes I made improved performance but it is still incredibly slow when compared to manually opening chrome and going to the YouTube homepage. What's got me scratching my head is the fact that a normal chrome browser in incognito is still loading all the resources on the site, and even with all that extra bloat it's still faster than puppeteer.

It leads me to think that YouTube is throttling the puppeteer client based on it being a bot, but between the stealth plugin and verifying that my user agent is valid (same user agent that's being used when I manually load the site) it still feels like I'm being throttled.

Any suggestions? Trying to find posts with this same issue is almost impossible, and the few that I've found with identical issues had no replies.

Comment: Running all of the "I'm not a bot" things doesn't guarantee they don't know you're a bot. These companies have serious resources to figure these things out if they feel it's in their interest to do so. If you mention what you need to automate youtube for, maybe someone can offer a completely different approach that solves your problem.